# If $\cos\alpha=\frac13,$ find the value of $7\cos(180^\circ-\alpha)-2\sin(90^\circ+\alpha)$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\cos\alpha=\dfrac13,$ find the value of $$7\cos(180^\circ-\alpha)-2\sin(90^\circ+\alpha)$$
Let $A=7\cos(180^\circ-\alpha)-2\sin(90^\circ+\alpha)=-7\cos\alpha-2\cos\alpha=-9\cos\alpha$ or when $\cos\alpha=\dfrac13\Rightarrow A=-9.\dfrac13=-3.$ The given answer in my book is $3$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Your work looks good to me - I think the book's wrong.

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha the book is wrong and you are right

Comment: I'd say it's a typo.

Comment: @Medi Regarding a different question : [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4149556/the-number-frac0-0000000000160-0000004-times200000000-is-equal-to?noredirect=1#comment8589878_4149556) I said I'd leave you links regarding decimal point and expanded notation, so I'll find some, many maybe, and drop it at a good place so you can see it. Thanks. We'll also have to talk about why the question was deleted as well, so I'll find a good time to do that.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, thank you!

Comment: @Medi The notation that is used for simplification of the expressions I showed you earlier is called scientific notation. Here are some articles : [(1)](https://www.varsitytutors.com/sat_math-help/how-to-convert-decimals-to-scientific-notation#:~:text=Correct%20answer%3A,-%5Cdisplaystyle%203.6%5Ccdot10&text=To%20convert%20a%20decimal%20into,a%20%22power%20of%2010%22.) , [(2)](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/exponent3.htm) , [(3)](https://www.storyofmathematics.com/converting-to-scientific-notation) let me know if you need resources in a different language as well.

Comment: Scientific notation is obviously more helpful for *cancellation*, since it's easier to find $\frac{10^{12}}{10^{17}}$ than $\frac{1000000000000}{100000000000000000}$. So that's where the trick was in that problem which got deleted. I hope I can help you like this in the future. If you have trouble writing questions, you can visit the [Constructive Feedback Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback) and we can give you directions on how to improve your post. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

$7 \cos(\pi-\alpha) = -7 \cos(\alpha) = -7/3$

$2 \sin(\pi/2 + \alpha) = 2 \cos (\alpha) = 2/3$

So you get $-7/3-2/3 = -3$.